# How to sort an array with a custom order in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

I have a collection of data like the following:

```
val data = Seq(
  ("M",   1),
  ("F",   2),
  ("F",   3),
  ("F/M", 4),
  ("M",   5),
  ("M",   6),
  ("F/M", 7),
  ("F",   8)
)
```

I would like to sort this array according to the first value of the tuple. But I don't want to sort them in alphabetic order, I want them to be sorted like that: all `F`s first, then all `M`s and finally all `F/M`s (I don't are about the inner sorting for values with the same key).

I thought about extending the `Ordering` class, but it feel quite overkilling for such a simple problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** *See @Eastsun's comment below for an even simpler solution.*

I finally came up with a simple solution based on a map:

```scala
val sortingOrder = Map("F" -> 0, "M" -> 1, "F/M" -> 2)
data.sortWith((p1, p2) => sortingOrder(p1._1) < sortingOrder(p2._1))
```

This will of course fail if there is a unknown key in `data`, but it will be fine in my case.

In order to avoid an error when a new key is met, we can do the following:

```scala
val sortingOrder = Map("F" -> 0, "M" -> 1, "F/M" -> 2)
val nKeys = sortingOrder.size
data.sortWith((p1, p2) => sortingOrder.getOrElse(p1._1, nKeys) < sortingOrder.getOrElse(p2._1, nKeys))
```

This will push tuples with unknown keys at the end of the list.

Comment: You are solution can be even simplified: `data.sortBy{ case(k, _) => sortingOrder(k) }`

Comment: Nice addition I couldn't think of a solution using only `sortBy`, thank you! Now that you pointed it it seems quite obvious indeed. Feel free to add it as another answer if you want!